# Attaching object to floor of environment map

Tags: three.js

Hi I have created an environment map that stitches 6 images to create a room, I have an object in the room that casts a shadow in attempt to make it look attached to the floor but I still get the effect that the object is floating in 3D space. Is there a way that I can get around this to glue the object to the ground. Keeping in mind the env map is rendered around the cameras position.

-- example1.js

```
function envMap(scene) {

    var testMaterials = [
      'image1.png',
      'image2.png',
      'image3.png',
      'image4.png',
      'image5.png',
      'image6.png'
    ];

    reflectionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( cubeMaterials );
    reflectionCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    scene.background = reflectionCube;

}
```

-- example1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
        minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
           body {
                margin: 0px;
                background-color: #000000;
                overflow: hidden;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="three.js"></script>

        <script>
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mesh;
            init();
            animate();
            function init() {

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                .shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                envMap( scene );

                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }
            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That code won't work my friend. Try to add a camera, lights and so on.
Help us to help you...

Comment: Sorry. My code does work I wrote this as an example and forgot those things. I was kind of hoping people would just understand what I was attempting and know a solution. The test code. At least to my understanding is meant to give people an understanding of what I am trying to do. I didn't think it needed to be 100% usable